# PHP Page Displays Blank Page and On Local same Script Downloading The Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a website on php, a Month Before it was working fine but Now i am facing an My Website is Not Loading, I hadn't Change Any thing. After This issue Reported I applied error reporting Lines in PHP File But its Not showing the Errors. so I downloaded the Whole Project and Runs That in Local. but in Local , WHen i Run PHP Script For only this Website it Downloads the Page every time. on Local I tried other script from any other page its working But Not on the web which is giving Issue.

Similarly The Web which is not Working right now. i have an Old Backup so i tried that too to run on local that backup is also doing the same issue.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: my website is Live on (http://systemscertification.com). It is showing blank Page Even i have Opened All types of PHP errors. What more One wants to know. Please ask

Comment: its not blank. its giving 500 Server Error. check server log.

Comment: Yeah. but On Local This error not showing its just downloading the Page. neither showing any Php error After Applying display Error Line Of Code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: _“After This issue Reported I applied error reporting Lines in PHP File But its Not showing the Errors”_ – well if your whole script can’t be parsed for some reason, then adding error reporting at runtime won’t work either of course. See to it that you set the appropriate values in the PHP configuration, not we runtime (see duplicate linked above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the Solution, The Problem was obsoleted Mysql Connection, as the Website was Created in 2014 on mysql Connection. For finding the Solution. I Removed All PHP Code First and Tried to Place The Code Lines One by One. and Then i got to the Solution that All Functions of PHP to SQL were on mysql which was the Issue, i converted All Functions in PDO and its working fine.

Thank You All of You For Contributing